# Record inheritance, is there a convenient syntax, perhaps on the way or not?

Tags: c#, inheritance, c#-record-type

I am trying to utilize records to reduce amount of boilerplate code and immediately spot the inconvenience of need to redefine all arguments of base record:

```
public record A(int a1, int a2, string a3, string a4, bool a5, bool a6, bool a7) { }
public record B(int b1, int b2, int a1, int a2, string a3, string a4, bool a5, bool a6, bool a7): A(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7) { }
public record C(string c1, string c2, int b1, int b2, int a1, int a2, string a3, string a4, bool a5, bool a6, bool a7): B(b1, b2, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7) { }
```

This bugs me. Here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BpnVoO).

Is there something I am missing? [Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) doesnt even have subtopic related to inheritance, probably because of being ashamed? Joking of course!

Perhaps something is planned for next C# release?

I am expecting syntax like following to exist:

```
public record B(int b1, int b2): A { }
```

which automatically produce constructor with all arguments from `B` and `A`. What is the point of record inheritance otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no shorthand syntax here. The inheritance is covered in the docs (see the [Positional parameters in derived record types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-parameters-in-derived-record-types) section):

> The following example illustrates inheritance with positional property syntax:

```
 public abstract record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
 public record Teacher(string FirstName, string LastName, int Grade)
     : Person(FirstName, LastName);
 public static void Main()
 {
     Person teacher = new Teacher("Nancy", "Davolio", 3);
     Console.WriteLine(teacher);
     // output: Teacher { FirstName = Nancy, LastName = Davolio, Grade = 3 }
 }
```

There are several discussions about similar topics:

- [Allow "inheriting" (record primary) constructor parameters](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6061)
- [Incremental primary constructor on record](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7424)

But nothing is planned AFAIK.

Also [Constructor Propagation](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/806) can be an interesting one.

Comment: I can swear that I was searching yesterday for text "inherit" on msnd page... and didn't found that.  The discussions you linked are interesting. `base` looks convenient and all base record constructors propagation would be cool to have.

Comment: Accepting "no" answer for now.. /sigh

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question - Positional parameters are, well, positional.
From what I understand, you're expecting the compiler to trust the developer to not screw up the positions of the parameters - and since we all know the first rule of programming is to never trust the user, I don't think that's a very realistic expectation.

The other point of having inheritance in records is that records are reference types and therefor polymorphic by nature, even if they do have value-type semantics.

Comment: If we are thinking of why not, then argument position is one thing. Another: there could be many constructors, which one should be used?